# How to scrape/automate an everchanging webgame using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, opencv, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm trying to automate a Webgame using selenium.
the problem that I have is the game is fast paced and needs to be interacted with otherwise you will loose the game and will be redirected to a different page.
So I never have enough time to properly analyze the HTML elements and write the code. is there any way to pause/save these interactions?

my other option is to just use OpenCV / image recognition

I have no idea where to start

Comment: you should be able to inspect the HTML elements. Which game is it ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.